# JSON Response Weirdly Formatted

Tags: python, json, rest, api, request

I would like to preface my question that this is the first time I've interacted with an API and JSON as I'm typically more on the Database sides of things.

With that, I'm a little confused with one of the APIs I'm currently working with.

I have a vendor that has an API that allows me to pull down some information about some of the users of that service.  The problem is that the response seems to not be in JSON, or if it is it isn't a version of JSON that I have seen.

The response looks like this.

```
{"Header":"Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4", "Rows":["Row1Value1,Row1Value2,Row1Value3,Row1Value4","Row2Value1,Row2Value2,Row2Value3,Row2Value4"]}
```

Which, seems wrong with everything that I've been doing with JSON so far.  I'm unable to interpret this in Python as anything use-able or Powershell.

Is this a type of format?  Or is this some weird thing that this vendor has generated that isn't JSON and needs to be interpreted as it's own thing?

Comment: Looks like a minimum-effort attempt at implementing "JSON" export. It's a JSON wrapper for a CSV file, basically. You can parse it partway as JSON and then iterate over the rows (splitting on comma) to extract the values.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a half-JSON implementation; the outer containers look like JSON, and you get a JSON list for the rows, but the inner contents of `Header` and each row in `Rows` looks like a string you'll need to tokenize yourself (split on commas).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a bit of confusion here. JSON means literally just JavaScript Object Notation. Anything that parses to a valid object in JS and is limited to the data types String, Bool, Int, Float, Array and Object is JSON.

So, is this JSON? Yes, beyond doubt. Is this good JSON? Not really. Unfortunately, the idea would be that you would be able to parse a JSON object into a tabular form, but here, you would have to split things yourself.

Using simple string manipulation (split()), you can easily parse the rows and restructure them to your heart's content.